# How to get a page / the beginning of a Section?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Good Day! I have a Word Document and a macro that takes content of that document and inserts it into another Document(with all boundaries, frames etc.), Basically unorganized into organized document.

I would like to check the first page of a section (and any section) and see if any table is present if so, exit the loop, and just readjust the page accordingly with our country document standards.
I have done mostly without checking a table on the first page of a new section.

```
  If objSection.Index = 1 Then 'the first section
  
  'I need to check if there is a table on the first page of a section
  Checking page size and orientation for the first Section.'(this is done)
  
  
  ElseIf objSection.Index > 1 Then 'other sections
  
  'practically the same thing, checking if a table exists on the first page of a section
  Checking page size and orientation for all other Sections.'(this is also done)

  End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following should get you there.

```
Function TableInFirstPageOfSection(sec As Section) As Boolean
  Dim secRange As Range, secStart As Long
  Dim tblRange As Range, tblStart As Long
  
  TableInFirstPageOfSection = False
  Set secRange = sec.Range
  secRange.Collapse wdCollapseStart
  secStart = secRange.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
  If sec.Range.Tables.Count > 0 Then
    Set tblRange = sec.Range.Tables(1).Range
    tblRange.Collapse wdCollapseStart
    tblStart = tblRange.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
    If tblStart = secStart Then TableInFirstPageOfSection = True
  End If
End Function
```